# How to set ZendStudio NOT to delete trailing spaces?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, zend-studio

I've just installed the latest Linux version of ZendStudio 9.0.4 Trial to test it out. And now when I save a file it removes all the trailing spaces inside that file which "damages" the SVN.

I know about the option `Preferences->PHP->Editor->Save Action->Remove trailing whitespace` and it's not checked neither inside the preferences nor inside project specific preferences. When it's checked it makes no difference.

**My question is** there some kind of quick fix maybe I should write something somewhere inside the settings file or this is just a bug and I'll have to wait until it's fixed ?

**edit:** it happends with all the built-in editors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of hours spent searching in the preferences I've finally found that checkbox udner

```
Window->Preferences->General->Editors->AnyEdit Tools
```

Inside the "Auto-Convert" tab there is a "Remove tailing spaces" checkbox